# Terminate user input when space character is detected in C

Tags: c, string, input

I was wandering if there is a way to terminate user input (using scanf or something similar) when the user enters a space character.

Comment: `scanf()` already does that. Did you mean terminate all further input?

Comment: The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) family of functions stops naturally on *any* whitespace for most formats.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the program to detect when the user hits the space bar prior to hitting enter?  If so, you'll need to put the tty into raw mode, and you need to realize that your solutions will be non-trivial.  Try looking into `ncurses`.

Comment: I want to do something like a while loop so that when a user enters a space character it does the same as it would when he would press enter.

Comment: There are *several* ways to do something that matches your general description.  You have not given us nearly enough information to judge which of them would meet your specific need.  Some source code exhibiting the problem would go a long way toward clearing this up.

Comment: "*using scanf or something similar*" there is nothing similar(ily ugly) to `scanf()`.

Comment: Maybe `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != EOF) { do_stuff(c); }`